# Clone Apt Packages Offline

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, apt

I'm trying to figure out how can I clone apt (.deb) packages from one machine to another without using a remote repository meaning only by transferring files from one machine to the next.

From what I have found, the apt-clone program (which comes by default) can export a list of the installed packages to, later on, be installed by another repository.

**I'm searching for a solution that is:**

1. Does **not** need to install the packages by reaching to a third server
2. Preferably one that comes built-in with ubuntu based machines

Thanks in advance!